# What is the difference in restricting single user mode with password through /etc/sysconfig/init and /etc/inittab in a Linux system?

Tags: linux, unix, boot, boot-loader

I was checking some sites for setting password protection in single user mode login in my Linux server (Oracle Enterprise Linux-OEL) .

In some places I saw the steps to add entry into inititab file like below .

```
su:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin
```

In some other places I could see adding the entry in /etc/sysconfig/init file like below .

```
SINGLE=/sbin/sulogin
```

So what is the difference in adding to any of these files . Are they doing the same task ? Basically I want to know if I add into any of the above file will it serve the purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note is `/etc/sysconfig/init` is strictly a Redhat Linux (and derivatives) convention. You won't find that file on a Debian or Slackware system for instance.

Second note, recently, many distributions are unfortunately switching to SystemD which does not use `/etc/inittab`.  If you need the simplicity of `/etc/inittab`, you may want to research the best distro for your needs which does not use SystemD of which there are only a handful (eg: Devuan, Slackware, Gentoo, et al.).

Also it's worth mentioning -- if you are trying to secure your linux system by way of `sulogin` (requiring a password when booted from single-user mode) be aware that anyone with a bootable USB stick, or CDROM can quite simply bypass sulogin by booting from another form of media.

It's quite difficult to secure physical access without cages and security cameras.

Comment: My Linux version is Oracle Enterprise Linux(OEL)